# How to access the IBoutlet in ViewController from the XIB file

Tags: ios, swift

I have my UIButton Outlet in UiView.xib file and I want to create an action/function which will change the text of the UILablel Outlet which is from another UIView.xib file.

I have already add both UIViews in my ViewController file but I have no idea how to create function to access the elements from the differnt XIB files and call them in function.

Here is my code of the ViewController file

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // UIView 1 (XIB File 1)
        if let addUIView1 = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("totalOz", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? totalOZVC {

            self.view.addSubview(addUIView1)

       // Button 120ml function
            addUIView1.button120ml.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonSelectGlassSize(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

    // UIView2 (XIB File 2)

        if let addUIView2 = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("GlassSelector", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? GlassSelectorVC {

            self.view.addSubview(addUIView2)

            addUIView2.labelGlassSelect.textColor = UIColor.white
            addUIView2.labelGlassSelect.text = "Select the size of Glass"
 }

    // Creating a function to call the Outlets from the XIB files

    @objc func buttonSelectGlassSize(sender: UIButton) {
        // Change the text of labelGlassSelect when user press the button 120mL
    }
```

Sorry I am still very new to Swift, please can you guys help me out.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call functions from different xibs back to your controller, use custom delegates methods. Below is tutorial

[Implementing delegates in Swift, step by step.](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef)

To update other class data from your controller make internal functions in other class and call them from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Made the global instance of `addUIView1` and `addUIView2`. In the `buttonSelectGlassSize` method, access the addUIView2 and update the text of label. Currently you have not global instance, so you are not able to update the label's text.